# Using custom table to feed drop-down list datasource

Tags: kentico

Let's assume that I have Custom Table named `Possible URL target parameters` with code name `xyz.PossibleTargets` with 2 columns:
`Explanation` and `Value`.
How to feed drop-down field on page type with data to have `Value` (from table) as `Value` and `Explanation` as `name` in drop-down?
What I already tried and it is not working:

1. Generate value;name pairs divided by newline and place it as List of options:

   z = ""; foreach (x in CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["xyz.PossibleTargets"].Items) {z += x.GetValue("Value"); z +=";"; z += x.GetValue("Explanation"); z += "\n" }; return z;

   Validator do no allow me to do such trick.
2. Set option `Macro expression` and provide enumerable object:

   CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["xyz.PossibleTargets"].Items

   In Item transformation: `{%Explanation%}` and in Value column `{%TargetValue%}`.

   This do not work also.

[Dropdown configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNF1J.png)

How to do this correctly? Documentation and hints on the fields are not helpful.

Kentico v11.0.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should do it without marking field as a macro. Just type there the macro. Take a look on screen [image: look on screen]

Comment: As a side note to the answer from @DawidJachnik, your macro in the dropdown configuration can read as follows: `GlobalObjects.CustomTables["xyz.PossibleTargets"].Items.Columns("Value,Explanation").OrderBy("Explanation")`.  You don't need to loop through the values yourself, Kentico will iterate through the results for you, applying the transformations provided.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a macro, use straight SQL, using a macro only complicates what appears to be a simple dropdown list.

```
SELECT '', '-- select one --' AS Explanation
UNION
SELECT TargetValue, Explanation
FROM xyz_PossibleTargets -- make sure to use the correct table name
ORDER BY ExplanationText
```

This should populate exactly what you're looking for without the complication of a macro.

Comment: Thanks, this is also working, but I was curious how can I unleash true power of K# and simple to use macro syntax ;).

Comment: It's powerful but also not needed and in this case could be performance restricting.